# Performing linear search with two fields from different text files

Tags: vb.net, linear-search

With the current coded i've realised it is mandatory to have separate text files instead of one text file for my computer science coursework. Searching and reading fields from one text file is simple enough for me, but i'm struggling to search two separate text files and displaying them within text boxes. The array of both files also increase in size when i input data of customer. The text files have several fields. The IF statements do the same thing but they are doing it via different search functions, is their any way i can do it through the same search regarding its coming from two different files?

Some of the text file contents:

1 text file:
1         7    LL11 3BY  C Brymbo

DwellingID - House num - postcode - tax band - Ward

the other text file:

2         James     King      06/06/1999 YJames07@gmail.com           uOI4gSqohd

customerID   -     F.name  -  L.name  -  DOB   -    Contact info    -   Password

This is for the click event, which is related to a linear search class:

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click

    If cbsearch.Text = "View customer details" Then
        customerrecord = linsearchCustomerId(customerobject, txtsearchdetails.Text)
        If customerrecord.firstname = "" Then 'Validation, if nothing has been entered a messagebox will appear notifying the user
            MsgBox("No customers found")
        Else
            lblCustID.Text = customerrecord.CustomerID 'put the field within the label or textbox designated
            txtfirstname.Text = customerrecord.firstname
            txtlastname.Text = customerrecord.lastname
            txtvote.Text = customerrecord.Eligibletovote
            txtcontactinfo.Text = customerrecord.contactinfo
            txtdob.Text = customerrecord.DOB
            lblpassword.Text = customerrecord.password
        End If
    End If
    If cbsearch.Text = "View customer details + dwelling" Then
        dwellrecord = dwellingdetailsearch(dwellingObject, txtsearchdetails.Text) 
        If dwellrecord.dwellingID = "" Then
            MsgBox("Dwelling details not found")
        Else
            lbldwellingid.Text = dwellrecord.dwellingID
            txthousenum.Text = dwellrecord.housenum
            txtaddress.Text = dwellrecord.address
            ComboBox1.Text = dwellrecord.taxband
            Cbward.Text = dwellrecord.wardname
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code of reading to text files:

```
Function getalllines() As String()
        Dim filedata() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Dir$(_CLfilename))
        Return filedata
End Function
```

Comment: Probably not many people here have the paperwork of you course. Difficult to say what's the difference in reading one or more files, since the content is unknown as it is the destination. IMO, you should post a sample of your data and a better description of the tasks your application should perform.

Comment: Have done sorry

Comment: The code you posted does not in any way relate to reading text files.

Comment: My apologies i'm rather new to coding.

Comment: Please, the first comment, post a few lines of each text file so we can see what the data looks.

Comment: In the first file you have 5 field names but 6 fields. It appears that file1 has nothing to do with file2. Yes?

Comment: you're very right sorry, this makes sense now, a foreign key needs to be within file 1 for it to work?